# Поиск по селектору с любым символом в конце JQUERY запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, как правильно написать запрос по селектору

```
$("#form-product #tab-general #input-name2")
```

где #input-name2 может быть #input-name3 и т.д. , т.е. любой символ в конце.

```
#input-name?
```

Как правильно сделать такой запрос.

Comment: $("#form-product #tab-general input[id*='input-name']") возможно так?

Answer (score 5):

Нет надобности писать все `id` в цепочке.

`$('[id^="input-name"]')`

Подробней можно [почитать тут](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[Какие бывают селекторы](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: В дополнение - можно и так:    $("[id*='input-name']")

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо =)